# How does ul li ul work and can I use a class for it?

Tags: html, css

So I was working on a code and I found this "ul li ul". I tried to understand this by creating a test file and try it myself. But I just can't figured it out. 
And I don't really know how its called (I have never seen it before) I can't really google it.

This is the code I used:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li {
  color: blue;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}
ul li ul {
  list-style-type: square;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <ul>
    <li>a.</li>
    <li>b.</li>
    <li>c.</li>
    <li>d.</li>
    <ul>
      <li>1.</li>
      <li>2.</li>
      <li>3.</li>
      <li>4.</li>
      <li>5.</li>
    </ul>
    <li>e.</li>
  </ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

And also how could you use this and creating a class because in a entire site I might use more ul and I don't want all have the same style.
For example .test li ul and  does this work?

I found the code in a much more difficult file and I can upload it if you want it.

Comment: it's called dropdown menu. If you google that, you'll find lots of tutorials, explanations etc.

Comment: You can call it as nested unordered list, actually your markup is invalid, <ul> is not permitted as immediate child of another <ul>.

Answer (score 0):

UL stands for Unordered List. Typically this would show as a bulleted list.

LI are list items, or each bullet point.

EXAMPLE:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

This code displays as the following:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3

If you wanted to style it you could add a class if you want all of your unordered lists to be the same, or an id if you want only that specific list a certain way.

Example:

```
<ul class="mylist"> </ul>
<ul id="listone"> </ul>
```

After that you would then use CSS to style the corresponding tags.

Comment: okay thanks, but you can also use "ul li" as a methode to style it?

Comment: @SupremeLeader yes, see the answer from dippas above, I believe you can. However, personally, that is not the way I would do it.